# Elmah for logging successful web requests

Tags: elmah

I really like elmah for logging errors but how about just the opposite? I want to use elmah to log successfull http requests (status code 200) for the purpose of web analytics. Anyone know where in the source code I may be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to use this instead of elmah http://stickybeak.codeplex.com/

Comment: this looks pretty useful. codeplex says it's still in alpha though. still worth checking out though. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [custom logging in IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/579/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---custom-logging/)?

I'm thinking that Elmah won't be able to log certain requests (especially if you use something like [output caching](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/154/walkthrough-iis-70-output-caching/) -- the ASP.NET runtime won't get called at all).  If you hook into IIS, you'll be able to get a plethora of information about each request.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to IIS for this particular issue. Just wondering though, do you know of a site analytics tool that has the ability to read and display custom iis logging fields?